# curl - How to escape < in parameter value

Tags: curl, escaping

Here is the curl command I'm executing

```
curl -F "context=<http://example.com>" \
     -F "Content-Type=text/plain" \
     -F "source=file" \
     -F "content=@members.nt;type=text/plain" \
     http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/XXX/add
```

I'm trying to load openrdf repository. It gives me an error because there is a "<"
character at in the value of "context" parameter.
How to escape this "<" so curl does not think that I'm trying to load file content into "context" parameter

The error from curl is:

```
curl: (26) couldn't open file "http://example.com>"
```

I've tried to escape it with \ and using < and %3C
but no luck because as soon as I try to do this then the other end is complaining that it did not get exactly  http://example.com

This is what is sent from the browser form

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryl8CUSIvy5962lwBF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="baseURI"


------WebKitFormBoundaryl8CUSIvy5962lwBF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="context"

<http://example.com>
------WebKitFormBoundaryl8CUSIvy5962lwBF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"

text/plain
------WebKitFormBoundaryl8CUSIvy5962lwBF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"

file
------WebKitFormBoundaryl8CUSIvy5962lwBF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"; filename="members.nt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------WebKitFormBoundaryl8CUSIvy5962lwBF--
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use curl's `--form-string` which is like `-F` but doesn't interpret leading `@` and `<`:

```
   --form-string <name=string>
          (HTTP)  Similar  to --form except that the value string for the named parameter is used literally. Leading '@' and '<' characters, and the ';type=' string in the value have
          no special meaning. Use this in preference to --form if there's any possibility that the string value may accidentally trigger the '@' or '<' features of --form.
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this helped me out so much