# How to pass special characters in curl PUT method

Tags: curl, special-characters, put

I am updating a password for the user using curl.

When I update the password with special characters, curl requests gets failed.

Curl Request:-

```
curl -v -f -u "admin:admin" "https://sample.com/users/1?pretty=true" -X PUT -F "password=@68bnD2vRQ"
```

Error:-

> couldn't open file "68bnD2vRQ"

How can I use the curl requests with special characters for PUT method?

FYI I am generating and assigning random password for the users. So I am not sure the position of special characters in the password, it may be any where in the string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl - How to escape < in parameter value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484313/curl-how-to-escape-in-parameter-value)

Comment: @orhtej2 Is there any special characters gets conflict in curl like '@' and '<' ? Because my random password contain these (!@#$%^&*+=) special characters. Will this "--form-string" is enough or need to any other solutions based on my above special characters?

Comment: --form-string only disables special meaning of < and @, see other special characters in https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html (--form). Notice that it depends on how you invoke curl - perhaps some of these are special characters in the shell you're using?

Comment: @orhtej2 I am not able to use "$" symbol in password string as it conflict with shell script. mypassword=$68bnD2vRQ , When I use password=$mypassword, curl request result in an error due to "$" symbol

Comment: It needs to be escaped, depends on the exact shell you're using. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856010/7034621 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the data from the standard input:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://httpbin.org/put -d@-
password=@68bnD2vRQ
```

The `-d@-` reads data from `stdin`.

Just in case by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> [terminates the input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character).